# Custom tabBarButton: component navigation in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm encountering an issue with a custom tab button component in my React Navigation application.

I have defined a custom tab button component called CustomTabBarButton and I want to use it as a button within the tab bar in a specific Tab.Screen. However, I'm facing a problem when I include it in the options of the Tab.Screen

```
import CustomTabBarButton from "../CustomTabBarButton/CustomTabBarButton";

///

<Tab.Screen
  name="AddButton"
  children={() => <HomeStackScreen user={user} />}
  options={{
    tabBarLabel: "",
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <Image
        source={imageUrl}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{
          width: 70,
          height: 70,
          backgroundColor: "#373737",
          borderRadius: 100,
        }}
      />
    ),
    tabBarButton: () => (<CustomTabBarButton navigation={navigation} setScreen={setScreen} />)
  }}
/>
```

Im getting the following error in the console:
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"TrackerSetttings"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'TrackerSetttings'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

In the same file TrackerSetttings is defined in the following way:

```
function HomeStackScreen({ navigation, user, backgroundColor }) {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Tracker Setttings"
        children={() => <TrackerSettings user={user} />}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          title: "Velg lokasjon",
        })}
      />
```

The issue is that it doesn't work when I include tabBarButton in the options. However, when I remove it, as shown below, it works as expected.

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="AddButton"
  children={() => <HomeStackScreen user={user} />}
  options={{
    tabBarLabel: "",
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <Image
        source={imageUrl}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{
          width: 70,
          height: 70,
          backgroundColor: "#373737",
          borderRadius: 100,
        }}
      />
    )
  }}
/>
```

I'm looking for insights into why the tabBarButton causes issues and how to resolve this problem so I can use my custom tab button component. Any help or guidance on the correct implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you trying passing the intrinsic props,
`tabBarButton: (props) => <CustomTabBarButton navigation={navigation} setScreen={setScreen} {...props} />
`

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you are getting the following error:
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"TrackerSetttings"} was not handled by any navigator.

So, according to your code snippet, I guess it's a typo. Try changing your name's value to "TrackerSetttings" instead of "Tracker Setttings" and see if it works -

```
<HomeStack.Screen
    name="TrackerSetttings"
    children={() => <TrackerSettings user={user} />}
    options={({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "Velg lokasjon",
   })}
/>
```